# How to fix an application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba

This macro works for me on my computer but it's giving me a headache when I ask my colleague to run it.

Any suggestions on why this is giving me trouble?

The macro works fine on my computer, but on my co-worker's computer, the Run-time error '1004' pops up... application-defined or object-defined error.  Debug brings me to the bottom of the script, just below 'resize each section on the summary page.

Thanks!

```
Sub Resize_Template()

'count records on pipeline tab
Dim pipe As Integer
With Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
pipe = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With
'count records on Lead tab
Dim Lead As Integer
With Sheets("Lead Data")
Lead = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With
'count records on approved tab
Dim App As Integer
With Sheets("Approved Closing Data Draw")
App = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With
'count records on mods tab
Dim Mods As Integer
With Sheets("Modifications")
Mods = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With
'resize each section on the summary page
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Template").Range("App_Close_btm").Resize(App - 2).EntireRow.Insert
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Template").Range("Modifications_btm").Resize(Mods - 2).EntireRow.Insert
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Template").Range("UW_btm").Resize(pipe - 2).EntireRow.Insert
'Lead section does not need to be resized at this time
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sure... the macro works fine on my computer, but on my co-worker's computer, the Run-time error '1004' pops up... application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: On which line? Please [edit] your post to *embed* all the relevant information.

Comment: edited comment, debug brings me to just below 'resize each section on the summary page... I'll look into how to embed

Comment: FWIW I've retracted my close vote, thanks for taking the time to make your question answerable :)

Comment: Is your co-worker using the same workbook as you, or is it a different workbook and you have just copied the macro across?

Comment: I created the template that I then load into conga composer.  Conga merges salesforce data into the file then my co-worker downloads it to her computer, and clicks a button which activates the macro.

Comment: I believe if `App - 2` is negative your code might raise the error you're getting. I'd suggest putting a breakpoint (F9) on the faulting line, and using the debugger to inspect the values the code is working with. There's probably a bad assumption somewhere, about the data that's supposed to be on the worksheets involved.

Comment: It sounds like `App` might have a value of 2, 1 or 0.  How many rows are used in their "Approved Closing Data Draw" sheet's column A?  If it stops at row 3 or less, you will error out.

Comment: Hmm... I'll check i out.  App is registering as 9, Mods as 4, and pipe as 14, so I don't think a negative value is creating the obstacle.

Comment: Also, is it possible that the range name "App_Close_btm" is right at the bottom of the worksheet (so that there is no room to add enough new rows)?

Comment: "App_Close_Btm" is 1 named cell that is located in the upper 3rd of the worksheet (row 5).  I mean, it works on my computer, but not on my co-workers.  Would it make a difference if I said to somehow insert as of the row of "App_Close_BTM" rather than just the cell name itself?

Comment: You need to *debug* it. Use breakpoints, watches, locals, `Debug.Print` calls to output relevant data to the *immediate pane* - *something* is passed to the `Resize` method that results in either an error, or a range reference for which it is illegal to call `.EntireRow.Insert` on. Is `App` "registering as 9" on the colleague's machine?

Comment: would something like: .Range("App_Close_Btm").row.resize(app-2_).entirerow.insert

Comment: Good point Matt. I will start there.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the named ranges are not present in your co-worker's copy of the workbook?  Perhaps they are not surviving the Conga process.